# How to change TITLE in blogspot.com?

Tags: blogspot

Please help how to edit template?
i want  will be like post.title

```
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://overapi.com/blogger) may help you.

Main code for page title is:

```
<title>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageName'>
    <data:blog.pageName/> - 
  </b:if>
  <data:blog.title/>
</title>
```